# adjust only iframe src from youtube

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

how can I adjust the width and height for all iframe that has only youtube link

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xbGv2T456dfg3">
```

because I have some the uses iframe also but I only need to adjust all iframe that has a youtube link.

css

```
iframe {width:560px;height:316px;}
```

need help on this

Answer (score 1):

Use an attribute selector:

```css
iframe[src^=http://www.youtube.com] {
    width:560px;
    height:316px;
}
```

If the link might be https, or some other variations, you can use the more liberal `*=` selector:

```
iframe[src*=.youtu] {
    width:560px;
    height:316px;
}
```

Comment: How browser compatible is that? ie9?

Comment: @Fresheyeball - I think IE7.

Comment: @Fresheyeball - According to [this article](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/05/ie7-css-selectors-how-they-fail/), IE7 has trouble with substring matching (though my own quick test seems to contradict that). IE8 handles it fine though.

Comment: can this be possible

$('iframe').each(function(){
    this.src = this.src('http://www.youtube.com/embed/');
    width:560px;
    height:316px;
})

the code is wrong, I know but the feel of it...